# Possibility to change the Kafka platform later without having any impact for table data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

If I implement Kafka Connect to sync 2 tables with Source and Sink connector, is there any possibility to change the Kafka platform later without having any impact for table data.

I use Kafka connect to sync data between micro services databases and I predict that there will be instances that I need to move from one Kafka instance to another.

Scenario:
If I have 100 records in table A, same 100 records will be available in table B too and Topic T1 is used to sync.
If I discard existing Kafka topic T1 and create a new topic T2 for the same task (or if I move from one Kafka cluster to another ), will it again bring 100 records in table A to table B, bringing about a duplication?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what extent you mean by "changing kafka platform".

Sink connectors store read records as any other consumer in a consumer group.

Group ids and their associated consumed topic offsets are stored back in a Kafka topic.

If you ever change clusters, ids, topics, etc you're effectively making a new consumer group, thus restarting what's already been consumed

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply. What I mean is currently we are using one specific cloud providers kafka instance. If we have a requirement to move from that to confluent kafka, keeping the same DB, from the day we switch to confluent kafka, it should start sync from the next record, and it should not sync the whole set of records that were there since beginning. I think this explains my issue.

Comment: 1) "confluent kafka" is not a thing, so the data format is not changing. 2) Feel free to read over the some docs around Replicator https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-deployments/replicator/index.html